# Place all code in one function?

Tags: php, text

This is the original

```
echo '<div style="float: right; width:31%; text-align: center; ">
      <img src="/img/1.png" width="12" height="12"/><em> '.
      $results['tagline']
      .' </em></span><img title="'.
      $results['tagline']
      .' "src="/img/2.png" width="12" height="12" "> </div><br>';
```

So where `.$results['tagline'].` is, I want to replace with this code below

```
$string = ' '.$results['tagline'].' '; 

$maxLength = 25;

if (strlen($string) > $maxLength) {
    $stringCut = substr($string, 0, $maxLength);
    $string = substr($stringCut, 0, strrpos($stringCut, ' ')); 
}
echo $string; 
echo '<span style=""><span title2="'.$results['tagline'].'" class="masterTooltip">...</span></span>';
```

Or if can correct all text properly to get code to work like I want!

Comment: '.$results['tagline'].' so i want that tagline text is maxLength ex 25 and after  25 Length it show ... and those ... is my costum tooltip where show full length tagline

Comment: tagline is movie tagline "Taglines: On September 11th, one of our darkest day in our history, 40 ordinary people sat down as strangers, and stood up as one." - http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0475276/?ref_=plg_rt_1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oh here it is, should i point out the html is now invalid ?

```
function title($t){
$string = ' '.$t.' '; 

$maxLength = 25;

if (strlen($string) > $maxLength) {
    $stringCut = substr($string, 0, $maxLength);
    $string = substr($stringCut, 0, strrpos($stringCut, ' ')); 
}
$out= $string; 
$out.= '<span style=""><span title2="'.$t.'" class="masterTooltip">...</span></span>';

return $out;
}

echo '<div style="float: right; width:31%; text-align: center; "><img src="/img/1.png" width="12" height="12" " /><em> '.title($results['tagline']).' </em></span><img title="'.$results['tagline'].'" src="/img/2.png" width="12" height="12" "> </div><br>';
```

Comment: you are master of coding, works perfecto first place it give me white page so in end was missing ; last code line :D